# Microphone is only detected when I plug in the first time after starting my PC

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

I have been facing this issue lately where my headphone is detected only during the first plugin. It won't be detected if I take it out and plug it in again.

The headphone has a single (2-in-1) cable and I use a splitter to divided it into a speaker and microphone.

I can restart the PC to get it detected again but that is very troublesome. What could be the possible reasons for this?

The headphones work fine as I have used them in other devices without any issues.

Thanks.

Comment: What make are your computer and headphone?

Comment: @harrymc The headphones are from Cosmic Byte and PC is assembled with a B360M motherboard.

Comment: Can you perhaps update BIOS and then go through USB devices in Device Manager and update them all.  Restart and see if any change.

Comment: Have you checked the [Cosmic Byte drivers](https://www.thecosmicbyte.com/download-drivers/)?

Comment: Thanks @harrymc. I have Cosmic Byte Spider Headphones. The drivers seem to be for Cosmic Byte Oberon Headset. Should I install them anyway?

Comment: Thanks @John but that sounds risky to me. :)

Comment: @harrymc Couldn't install the driver anyway as it asks to plugin that specific headset.

Comment: Updating BIOS on a home built machine might have some risks, but updating USB devices in Device Manager should not be risky

Comment: Do oyou have realtek drivers?Or most importantly Realtek Audio console installed?

Comment: @Indiano Yes, I have Realtek Audio Console Installed but it shows the message `Realtek Audio console doesn't support for this machine.` :)

Comment: @Indiano I also seem to have Realtek drivers installed because list of devices in sound control panel under recording shows `Realtek (R) Audio` under Microphone, Stereo Mix and Line In etc.

Comment: My next question would be, do you have a laptop that should be switching autonomosly from headphones to speakers?

Comment: If yes, I think I might know whats the issue. something cheesy happened with some process that should start on startup but does not, in my case was the whole Realtek packet, it should be wort a shot  too look into it

Comment: Thanks @Indiano but I use a PC and the headphones don't have bluetooth connectivity. My brother uses a laptop but he never uses the headphones that I use. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Enable "Realtek" on startup**


Try enabling "Realtek HD Audio Universal Service" on computer startup...that solved the issue in my case.

**Steps :**

1. Search for "startup apps" in windows search
2. Open it
3. Enable the "Realtek HD Audio Universal Service"
4. Restart your PC

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).